# Protractor, how to test user accounts?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am wondering what's the best approach is regarding end-to-end testing. If I understand it correctly the idea end-to-end testing is to cover user stories and test them in automatic manner. For example, using Protractor for Angular.js application.

In my current project you are capable to create user accounts and login in. How does this work? Would you use a specifically prepared database to test logging into an account. Also what about the registration process. How should this be tested? Are their any best practices regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that ideally you have a known database backup or a script that cleans up your test DB.  Then you can make a part of the testing process either restoring that DB or running the script.
The script might be simpler to implement.  You can pull in whatever node modules you need to execute it as a part of running the test suite rather than it being an external step.

Alternately, I am working on a system that has a complex user creation and syncing process.  So, we have other external systems that the app has to interact with, which cannot be easily reset/restored.  Instead we've taken the approach of having a REST service exposed that can work with the other system to, for example, find a user with a certain set of characteristics.  Then, as a part of the spec, we make a call to this service and get a valid user for our test case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are two approaches to this problem:

1. Make your tests point to a real database that is a copy of your production environment one. This will make tests check if your database is properly accessed and data is returned as you expect. This is a possibility but not the correct to me as e2e testing should check the client frontend experience and not how the app is leaning on the backend part.
2. Make use of a mock backend. A mock backend is kind of a "fake server" that you can develop at client side to return the information you need to make your application work. I think this is the correct approach as you focus on making your APP work regardless of the server possible issues.

You can see an example in this tutorial:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/building-your-first-tests-for-angular5-with-protractor-a48dfc225a75

To be more concrete, in this file:
https://github.com/shootermv/protractor-tutorial/blob/master/src/app/_helpers/fake-backend.ts

Greetings.